# Porting Ubuntu Touch to 4Good s450m 4G

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, porting-ubuntu-touch

I have this smartphone and i want porting Ubuntu Touch to him. https://market.yandex.ru/product/13472344/spec?hid=91491&track=tabs
This device have analogical tech specs with BQ Aquaris M4.5, except display, camera, battery and some sensors.
Can i change BQ official image for working with my phone, or i need go another way?

Also i install to him unofficial image of CM-based OS (TeslaOS), and have images of clean CM and AOSP for my device.

Sorry for my english :)
And, if it possible, please give me answer on russian :)

Comment: The answers in the 'duplicate' question are so old they have got whiskers on them!  Up to date instructions are here https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/phone/devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/   Please don't offer that duplicate again.